# Remove empty paragraph elements from HTML via SQL

Tags: html, sql-server, optimization

Post has been edited because the phrasing and structure of the original post was asking for the work to be done for me as opposed to the best method to complete the work.

**Problem**

Email template (shown below) contains tags (encapsulated in '$' characters), these tags are replaced with relevant data (if not null) via a SQL Server trigger. After processing, there may be instances where the tags are not replaced.

I could just replace the tags with empty varchars, but this will cause the email to contain large areas of whites space when rendered in an email client or the browser.

Embedding JavaScript into the email is a consideration for later development but that is outside the scope of what I am doing. This has to be achieved purely through **SQL**.

**Question**

What is a more intelligent way to achieve the same results?

**Tags**

```
$ChargeAmount_Changed$
$StartDate_Changed$
$EndDate_Changed$
$EscalationAmount_Changed$
$AccountCode_Changed$
$COSAccountCode_Changed$
$InvoiceDesc_Changed$
$BillingPeriod_Changed$
$BillingCycle_Changed$
$FinanceParty_Changed$
$FinanceAmount_Changed$
$BillingCustomerCode_Changed$
$ChargeAmount_Crtitical$
$StartDate_Critical$
$EndDate_Critical$
$EscalationAmount_Critical$
$AccountCode_Critical$
$COSAccountCode_Critical$
$InvoiceDescription_Critical$
$BillingPeriod_Critical$
$BillingCycle_Critical$
$FinanceParty_Critical$
$FinanceAmount_Critical$
$BillingCustomerCode_Critical$
```

**Code**

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_bpo_SALSEmail_RemoveTags(
        @Html       VARCHAR(MAX)
,       @EmailFlag  VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
WITH    ENCRYPTION
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RowID INT
    ,   @Tag VARCHAR(50)
    ,   @StartIndex INT = 0
    ,   @EndIndex INT
    ,   @StartTag VARCHAR(50)
    ,   @EndTag VARCHAR(50)
    ,   @RowVar VARCHAR (MAX)
    ,   @DeterminedRow INT = 0

    DECLARE @Tags TABLE    (
        fldTagID    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,   fldTag      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO @Tags
    SELECT      fldTag 
    FROM        tblSALSEmailLoopingFields WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE       fldEmailFlag = @EmailFlag 


    SELECT @RowID = COUNT(fldTag) FROM @Tags

    WHILE @RowID <> 0
    BEGIN   
        SET @DeterminedRow = 0
        SELECT  @Tag = fldTag 
        FROM    @Tags
        WHERE   fldTagID = @RowID

        SET @StartIndex = PATINDEX('%' + @Tag +'%', @Html)
        SET @EndIndex = @StartIndex + LEN(@Tag)

        -- Expression found
        IF @StartIndex > 0
        BEGIN
        -- Have not found the whole row yet
        WHILE @DeterminedRow = 0
        BEGIN
            --See if the index is at the start of the opening paragraph element for the row
            SET @StartTag = SUBSTRING(@Html, @StartIndex, LEN('<p'))

            --See if the index is at the end of the closing paragraph element for the row
            SET @EndTag = SUBSTRING(@Html, @EndIndex,  LEN('</p>'))
            --March the start index back
            IF @StartTag <> '<p' 
            BEGIN
                SET @StartIndex = @StartIndex - 1
            END

            --March the end index forward
            IF @EndTag <> '</p>'
            BEGIN
                SET @EndIndex = @EndIndex + 1
            END

            -- Found the whole row! replace with empty var
            IF @StartTag = '<p' AND @EndTag = '</p>'
            BEGIN
                SET @DeterminedRow = 1
                -- Get the whole row
                SET @RowVar = SUBSTRING(@Html, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - @StartIndex + LEN(@EndTag))
                SET @Html = REPLACE(@Html, @RowVar, '')
            END
        END
        END
        SET @Html = REPLACE(@Html, @Tag, '') 
        SET @RowID = @RowID - 1
    END

    RETURN @Html
END
```

**HTML Template**

```
-- Start of template
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .cs2654AE3A {
            text-align: left;
            text-indent: 0pt;
            margin: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt
        }

        .cs37BA8FCA {
            color: #000000;
            background-color: transparent;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 9pt;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">A contract item fee has been ??fldAction?? on Contract No.
            ??fldContractNo?? , for customer ??fldCustomerCode?? .</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">The fee ??fldAction?? is ??fldFeeType??</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">Located on ??fldItemType?? : ??fldItemCode??</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$ChargeAmount_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$ChargeAmount_Crtitical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$StartDate_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$StartDate_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$EndDate_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$EndDate_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$EscalationAmount_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$EscalationAmount_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$AccountCode_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$AccountCode_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$COSAccountCode_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$COSAccountCode_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$InvoiceDesc_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$InvoiceDescription_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$BillingPeriod_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$BillingPeriod_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$BillingCycle_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$BillingCycle_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$FinanceParty_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$FinanceParty_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$FinanceAmount_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$FinanceAmount_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$BillingCustomerCode_Changed$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">$BillingCustomerCode_Critical$</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">This change was made by : ??fldEmpFullName??</span></p>
    <p class="cs2654AE3A"><span class="cs37BA8FCA">&nbsp;</span></p>
</body>

</html>
-- End of template
```

Answer (score 0):

For my opinion, this is not for what a database is developed.

My guess here is, search for a tag which is not removed, then search backwards for

```
<p
```

save this patindex, search forward to

```
</p>
```

, now you can delete all between the patindex. (don`t forget to calculate the searchstrings here)

Another approach could be:
If you have to deal with such task, you can easy do this in frontend with JavaScript/jQuery.

```
$('p').each(function( index ) {if($(this).html() === '') { this.remove()}})
```

This will stripe out all paragraph which are empty.

**EDIT:**

Loop thru the html and select every paragraph into a temp table.
Then you can handle it easy.

```
declare 
    @tbl TABLE(
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [paragraph] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
    );

declare 
    @HtmlLen INT = LEN(@Html)
    ,@StartIndex INT = 0
    ,@EndIndex INT


WHILE CHARINDEX('<p', @Html)>0
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @StartIndex = CHARINDEX('<p', @Html),
        @EndIndex = CHARINDEX('</p>', @Html)

    INSERT INTO @tbl([paragraph])
    select SUBSTRING ( @Html ,@StartIndex, @EndIndex -4 )
    select @Html = SUBSTRING(@Html, @EndIndex+3, @HtmlLen)

END

select * from @tbl
```

the result
[image]

you can rebuild your html string with (for SQL2017+)

```
 -- at least build up your string again
 SELECT STRING_AGG([paragraph], '')  FROM @tbl
```

Comment: That is a great suggestion! I have considered this, but it is outside the scope of what I am doing, I have managed to remove the paragraph elements from the template, what I wanted to know is if there are betters ways of removing the elements via SQL other than what I have done. 

The original post has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: Actually I am not. At the desk, but I guess there might be a  second solution. I will have a look later